# Google maps background is gray

Tags: ios, google-maps

If you're like me, you might be searching all of the internet to fix this problem. Every post will be saying

> If you have a gray background it's your API key

but we thought we were special. Even our

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
```

was returning with `True`.

We checked that:

- our API key was the iOS key
- that google maps was enabled
- that the key matched what was on the console
- our bundle identifier was correct

Nothing worked.

Comment: You already tried to create a new project from scratch and do all steps again? Like create an `UIView` in your initial View Controller, set the `UIView` as GMSMapsView and add all the SDK config functions in the app delegate?

Comment: @kileros Correct. The problem has been solved as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We stored out API key in a file, so we could add it to our `.gitignore`. Turns out when you're reading in your API key you're going to want to be absolutely sure that you're trimming `\n`s from your string.

I hope this helps at least one other person!

Comment: This has been put into the post edit, you may delete this.

Comment: @TrooperZ, this is the solution and not the part of question.